# How to search for a JSON key in a database column (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, json, database

I want to search for a specific key inside a json object that is stored in my database.

Usually to get a value I use something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM orders 
WHERE JSON_VALID(producten) 
AND JSON_SEARCH(producten,"one", "60c072619e257") IS NOT NULL
```

But this returns nothing, while a column in my `orders` table contains the following json:

```
{
   "60c072444173b":{
      "naam":"Foto op paneel ",
      "alias":"foto-op-paneel",
      "url":"https:\/\/website.nl\/new\/plaat\/foto-op-paneel",
      "afbeelding":"cms\/images\/producten\/plaat-poducten\/Foto_op_paneel\/F.jpg",
      "aantal":"3",
      "hoogte":"90",
      "breedte":"90",
      "uploaden":"1",
      "edit_status":"finished"
   },
   "60c072619e257":{
      "naam":"Universele folie",
      "alias":"universele-folie",
      "url":"https:\/\/website.nl\/new\/product\/universele-folie?term=u",
      "afbeelding":"cms\/images\/producten\/universele-folie\/thumbnail\/orajet_folie_wit.jpg",
      "aantal":"4",
      "hoogte":"100",
      "breedte":"100",
      "uploaden":"1",
      "edit_status":"finished"
   },
   "60c0728865f04":{
      "naam":"Naadloos fotobehang",
      "alias":"naadloos-fotobehang",
      "url":"https:\/\/website.nl\/new\/product\/naadloos-fotobehang",
      "afbeelding":"assets\/images\/custom\/noimgprint.jpg",
      "aantal":"1",
      "hoogte":"90",
      "breedte":"90",
      "uploaden":"1",
      "edit_status":"finished"
   }
}
```

Probably because what I am searching for is a key and not a value. Is it possible to search for a key instead?

Comment: If `producten` is not valid JSON then the query should fail. `WHERE JSON_VALID(producten)` won't help - 2nd condition will be evaluated anycase.

Comment: `JSON_SEARCH(producten,"one", "60c072619e257")` You must search in the output of JSON_KEYS(), not in JSON itself.

Comment: @Akina Without the check for valid json an error is thrown when 1 row of that column is empty or does not contain valid json and my code breaks. With the check it searches and just ignores empty rows or invalid json rows.

Comment: Another, not JSON-processing, columns in output saves you. However, this may depend on the exact version and SQL Mode...